# Send additional data to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am currently using Google Analytics on our site . We have a lot of extra data(e.g net revenue/gross revenue etc) which is being passed to analytics via DATALAYER.
I can see the data being passed correctly via data layer. But cannot identify  how can we update the Sales Performance chart in GA to view the passed data.

Can you help me with identifying how can we view additional transaction level data being sent to GA?

Answer (score 1):

You can not send transaction data just like it. You need to either use correctly formated [Ecommerce dataLayers](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce) or [upload cost data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2803329?hl=en) which can be configured here:

[image: cost]

In there you can configure the structure you will need to upload the data and you can either upload it manually in csv (they generate already formated CSVs based on what configured before and you just need to fill the blanks) or [via API request](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-cost).